# Pass arguments from csh to program, exactly as they are

Tags: linux, csh

I have a csh script, which is executed using "source", and passes all its arguments to a program:

```
% alias foo source foo.csh
% cat foo.csh
./bar $*
# Some uninteresting stuff
```

If I run `source foo.csh a b c`, all is OK. But not always:

1. `foo "a b" "c d"`:
   I expect `bar` to get two arguments - `a b` and `c d`. Instead, it gets 4.
2. `foo a "*" b`:
   The `*` is expanded to a list of files. I just want the character `*`.
   Extra credit - `foo a * b` should work the same way. I know it's more problematic and I'm willing to live without it.

One thing I tried is changing `./bar $*` to `./bar "$*"`. This helps with the asterisk, but now `bar` always gets everything in a single parameter.

Notes:

1. Our company uses csh as the login shell, so I must use it when using `source`. Knowing that [csh programming is considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), I implemented all logic in `bar` and left the bare minimum in the script.
2. If you suggest redefining the alias, it's important to see that redirection still works (`foo | grep hello`), and that there's proper cleanup if ctrl-C breaks the script.

Answer (score 25):

Meanwhile, I've found the answer myself:

`./bar $argv:q`

The `:q` modifier takes care of things. It passes to `bar` the exact same parameters `foo` got.

Source: http://www.staff.tugraz.at/reinfried.o.peter/unix/cshell.html